# python win32com excel border formatting

Tags: python, excel, border, win32com

I have a piece of code here that actually work to format the borders in excel using python win32com.  My concern is the time it take to format the borders.  I tried to record a macro in excel to find out the required information to transpose it in my script but it didn't work.

So the best that I can do is to run in a for range loop where I always start at row 3 up to a row counter called shn[1] by increment of 1 and from column 1 to 10 by increment of 1.  From there I use "BorderAround()" which work fine but too slow.  Here my piece of code:

```
for shn in [("Beam-Beam", bb_row, bb_col), ("Beam-Col", bc_row, bc_col)]:
sheet = book.Worksheets(shn[0])
sheet.Range( "J3:DW3" ).Copy()
if shn[0] == "Beam-Col":
    sheet.Range( "J3:AA3" ).Copy()
sheet.Range( sheet.Cells( 4, 10 ), sheet.Cells( shn[1]-1, 10 )  ).PasteSpecial()
for mrow in xrange(3,shn[1],1):
    for mcol in xrange(1,10,1):
        sheet.Cells(mrow, mcol).BorderAround()#.Border(1)
```

Is there something I can do to format the borders with a range like ==>  sheet.Range( sheet.Cells(3,1), sheet.Cells(shn[1],10) )?  I tried ".Borders(11)" and ".Borders(12)" plus ".BorderAround()", but only ".BorderAround()" have worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, what excel are you using?

This should work:

```
for shn in [("Beam-Beam", bb_row, bb_col), ("Beam-Col", bc_row, bc_col)]:
sheet = book.Worksheets(shn[0])
sheet.Range( "J3:DW3" ).Copy()
if shn[0] == "Beam-Col":
    sheet.Range( "J3:AA3" ).Copy()
## Set a variable named rng to the range
rng = sheet.Range( sheet.Cells( 4, 10 ), sheet.Cells( shn[1]-1, 10 )  )
rng.PasteSpecial()
## Using this range, we can now set its borders linestyle and weight
##  -> where 7 through 13 correspond to borders for xlEdgeTop,xlEdgeBottom,
##     xlEdgeRight, xlEdgeLeft, xlInsideHorizontal, and xlInsideVertical
##  -> LineStyle of 1 = xlContinous
##  -> Weight of 2 = xlThin
for border_id in xrange(7,13):
    rng.Borders(border_id).LineStyle=1
    rng.Borders(border_id).Weight=2
## And to finish just call
book.Close(True) # To close book and save
excel_app.Quit() # or some variable name established for the com instance
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Also it may be faster if you set the excel applications Visible to False or turned off screenupdating:

```
excel_app.Visible = False # This will not physically open the book
excel_app.ScreenUpdating = False # This will not update the screen on an open book
##
# Do Stuff...
##
# Just make sure when using the ScreenUpdating feature that you reenable it before closing
excel_app.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This way excel isn't updating the screen for every call.